# php read file replacing first and second of something differently

Tags: php

I am reading a file line by line.

Some lines will have something like `-b-Bar Foo-b-` or `-h-Foo Bar-h-`.
I would like to be able to replace the first occurrence such as `-b-` would be replaced with `<b>` the second occurrence would be replaced with `</b>`.

Here's my current code for reading the file:

```
$handle = fopen($postDir, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

                      //<-- replace and checking goes here?

        echo '<p class="content">' .$line. '</p>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo '<h1 class="alert fade">Unable to read Article</h1>';
};
```

tags that I am using:

- `-b-` for `<b></b>`
- `-i-` for `<i></i>`
- `-u-` for `<u></u>`
- `-h-` for `<h1></h1>`

Is this possible, to check for each tag and replace first/second occurrence differently?

Comment: just to let you know the answer you accepted contains a regex that's greedy, the result of : `-b- something -b-  test test -b- another -b-` will be `<b>something -b-  test test -b- another </b>` - check the wrong regex here: http://ideone.com/c5xnUJ

Comment: A note hinting to your correct answer would have been sufficient :). I fixed my answer in the meantime and honored your helpful input :).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For `-b-`, `-i-` and `-u-` you can use this line

```
$line = preg_replace("/-([biu])-(.*)-([biu])-/iU", "<$1>$2</$3>", $line);
```

For `-h-`, you can use this one:

```
$line = preg_replace("/-h-(.*)-h-/iU", "<h1>$1</h1>", $line);
```

**Update**: Added ungreedy modifier after a comment from Pedro.

**Update 2**: Removed `|`s from character classes after helpful comment from @l'L'l

Comment: The `OR` inside the character class doesn't do what you think it does; it's a literal, so you are matching `|`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$line = <<< LOB
test -b- 123 -b- another test -h- hi there -h-
LOB;

$line = preg_replace('/-(b|i|u|h)-(.*?)-(b|i|u|h)-/sim', '<$1>$2</$3>', $line);

echo $line;
```

---

Output:

```
test <b> 123 </b> another test <h> hi there </h>
```

---

DEMO

http://ideone.com/LdcMbO

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Here I first get your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) where every line is one array element. There I ignore new line characters and skip empty lines.

After this I go through each line with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to check if it matches the pattern. If yes I replace the tags an return it back.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $lines = preg_replace_callback("/-(b|i|u|h)-(.*?)-(b|i|u|h)-/i", function($m){
        if($m[1] == "h" && $m[3] == "h")
            return "<" . $m[1] . "1>" . $m[2] . "<" . $m[1] . "1>";
        return "<" . $m[1] . ">" . $m[2] . "<" . $m[1] . ">";
    }, $lines);

    print_r($lines);

?>
```

And if you want to save the file back just use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), like this:

```
file_put_contents("test.txt", array_map(function($v){return $v . PHP_EOL;}, $lines));
```